# How to handle multiple "if" statements?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
            # Read the CSV file into a pandas dataframe
            df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep='|', header=0)

            for col in df.columns:
                #Check if the word "date" is in the column name
                if "date" in col.lower():
                    # Convert the column to a datetime type
                    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
                elif "payment_tier_number" in col.lower():
                    # Convert the column to a float type
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(float/decimal???)
                elif "number" in col.lower():
                    # Convert the column to an int type
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
                else:
                    # Convert the column to a string type
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
```

I am not sure if I am using `elif` and `else` in the correct way here. I want to convert the data type for columns that have "date" in it to "datetime", else if the column name is "payment_tier_number" then make it a decimal, else if there is "number" in the column name make it a "int" data type, and the rest string. I am able to get 1 "if" statement working but I am confused with multiple.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I would put `col = col.lower()` at the beginning so you don't have to keep repeating it.

Comment: You might want to "pre-read" the first row of the CSV file, find the actual column names, and construct an appropriate dict to pass as the `dtype`argument to `read_csv`.

Comment: there is no way to convert to decimal in python? i am trying to convert it to 'decimal' specifically so it reads in athena that way?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of if conditions looks good. But there is a little thing at the line "payment_tier_number" column conversion. I think, instead of float/decimal, it should be float.

```
df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
```

Comment: there is no way to convert to decimal in python? i am trying to convert it to 'decimal' specifically so it reads in athena that way,

Comment: You might try 'Decimal(df[col])'. Don't forget the 'from decimal import Decimal' instruction.